# Maven dependency cannot find its resources

Tags: maven, dependencies, classpath

I have two Maven projects in Netbeans, com.foo.bar and com.foo.baz.

com.foo.bar is a dependency of com.foo.baz.

```
bar
+-src
| +-main
|   +-java
|   | +-com
|   |   +-foo
|   |     +-bar
|   |       +-App.java
|   +-resources
|     +-com
|       +-foo
|         +-bar
|           +-config.properties
+-target
| +-classes
|   +-com
|     +-foo
|       +-bar
|         +-App.class
|         +-config.properties
+-pom.xml
```

When, in Netbeans, I click to expand project baz->dependencies->bar->com.foo.bar, I see same contents as bar/target/classes/com/foo/bar. All good, I think.

com.foo.bar has the lines

```
// print current directory
System.out.println(new File(".").getAbsolutePath());

// load config files
Properties conf = new Properties();
conf.load(new FileInputStream(config.properties));
```

com.foo.baz is similar, but with nothing in `resources/`. When I build-with-dependencies com.foo.bar and com.foo.baz and then run com.foo.baz, I get

```
/home/user/NetBeansProjects/baz/.
java.io.FileNotFoundException: config.properties (No such file or directory)
```

Is this a problem with the classpath, or what? Shouldn't Maven be handling this?

Comment: try with getClass().getResourceAsStream("com/foo/bar/config.prioperties")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the whole path to the file, like so

```
conf.load(new FileInputStream("com/foo/bar/config.properties"));
```

If you placed the file in the root folder inside resources, it'd work without the path.

```
bar
+-src
| +-main
|   +-java
|   | +-com
|   |   +-foo
|   |     +-bar
|   |       +-App.java
|   +-resources
|       +-config.properties
(...)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to load the `config.properties` from the `App` class then you can do it like this:

```java
public class App {

    public void someMethod() {
        InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream("config.properties");
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        try {
            properties.load(is);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("foo = " + properties.getProperty("foo"));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        App app = new App();
        app.someMethod();
    }
}
```

The `config.properties` is relative to the class that is used with `getResourceAsStream()`.